# Open "Spelling and grammar" window from objective-c osx

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm implementing a menu to our Mac OSX application. I a menu item with the standard "Spelling and grammar" to be opened when clicking.

Can't seem to find anywhere info on how to open this window from code. I assume this window is standard in OSX rather then implemented by all applications.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SpellCheck/SpellCheck.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000092-SW1

does not provide any information about opening the window but just how to spell-check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSSpellChecker gives you access to the spellingPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSSpellChecker_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSSpellChecker/spellingPanel), which you can then open like a regular window (NSPanel is subclassed from NSWindow, so you have access to things like ["`makeKeyAndOrderFront:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/makeKeyAndOrderFront%3a)).